# Error occuring when trying to write R.id variable

Tags: android

when I am trying to create edit view for my application, as i set R.id value as follows .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private EditText edittext1,edittext2;  
private Button buttonSum;  
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton(); 
}

private void addListenerOnButton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     edittext1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); //line1

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

An Error is showing in line 1 as **editTest1 cannot be resolved or not a variable.**
As in tutorial it is shown that R.java will be dynamically adds these variables into id class.

my activity_main.xml file under layout folder::

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance..
P.S::any links for good andriod tutorials

Comment: `EditTest1` not exists in this code..

Comment: please post your layout file

Comment: also post your import statements where is `EditTest1`

Comment: "R.java will be dynamically adds these variables into id class" it adds the `id`s to `R.java` but **only after** you have created the `View` with the `id` in your `layout` file. And that just gives them an `int` `id` so you can reference them.

Comment: sure you are not referencing the wrong layout coz your layout has not edittext or button. The tutorial that you are following seems to mislead you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If we had an idea of what you're trying to do we might be able to better help you out. From what I see you have a click listener set up to do something with an EditText on a layout that only has a TextView.

Answer (score 1):

The posted layout does not have a `EditText` with id `editText1`. You need to have an `EditText` in the layout that you set to the `Activity` and then initialize the `EditText`.

If you want to initialize TextView then

```
<TextView
 android:id ="@+id/tv1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Then

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout you need to update it to include said EditText. For example, below the default TextView that is given to you on setup:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    .... more set parameters
    // for example
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
/>
```

And then do the same for the second text field. Note that where you see @string, these are values that are set in your res/strings.xml file so you might want to take a look at those to see what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

You need set id property in XML

```
<TextView
    **android:id="@+id/editText1"**
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created the EditText in the layout. You must do that before the EditText shows up under R.id

Add this to your layout code:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Also, when you are declaring the EditText in your Java code it should look like this:

```
final EditText edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

As far as a good site for Android tutorials just search through http://developer.android.com. They have plenty of tutorials, sample applications and information on how to program Android applications.

Answer (score 0):

There is no edit text element in your code so , R.id can not refer to anything.

add the below code to your main layout.xml and all will work fine for you.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```